# How do i set sate based on the condition in checkbox Change function reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

In the checkbox the default value is null and I am setting it as true when required
but also I thought of one more condition that needs to be set when the checkbox is already selected I want to unselect it and set the value as false instead of null.

Assume alwaysSelected -if this is selected it is true(onload) based on this condition i should update the state

```
this.state = {
checkbox: null,
}
this.props.alwaysSelected=true

<Checkbox
onChange={this.ChangeValue}
/>

ChangeValue= (event) => {
this.setState(checboxState=> ({
checkbox: checboxState.checkbox ? null : true
});
})
```

Just say prevState.checkbox -true on a load of the page then it just gives null but need to set it as false

Option tried is setState callback and componentDidUpdate but failed to acheive.

can we do this in another approach??

Comment: Do you get the checkBox value from parent component or data fetch?

Comment: @Hesam from Parent Component -state value{checkbox: null}

Comment: what is event value in changeValue function? is it true/false?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the checkbox state to the Checkbox component as value and change the event:

```
ChangeValue = () => this.setState({checkbox:!checkbox});
```

or if event returns true/false

```
 ChangeValue = event => this.setState({checkbox:!event});
```

Comment: if there is a condition that your state is just null or true you can use "!!checkbox" to convert null to false.

Comment: how do i manage null value yes i need null value some time
do you mean using "!!checkbox" will convert it to false

Comment: e.g you use !!value, if value was null will convert to false and if it was true it will be true.

Comment: instead of checboxState should i just add ur code??

Comment: But what if i need null value also

Comment: try that, I think It is better to deal with true/false value in checkbox components.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244194/discussion-between-r9102-and-hesam).